# How to use a database to show a list view with pictures and text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application that will show a simple listview. The listview will show the contents of a specific table of a SQLite database.

In the database table I have 3 fields. `ID, Name and Picture`.

An example row would be:

```
ID : 1
Name : Glass
Picture : @drawable/glass
```

Would it be possible to use a List View to view this information, or any other way.
I need the ListView to show the ID, then the Picture, then the Name in one ListView section, if that makes sense.

Thanks

//EDIT
Also, the database is in the assets folder of the app, is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: of course you can use list view for that purpose better create an adapter for that purpose extending the base adapter

Comment: no you need to keep your database in internal memory or SDcard. Once your app launched you need to copy from assets folder to internal or External memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code loads a list view with an image and a textview refer it and edit for your use (sample code from lazy adapter)

```
public class abcdadapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dat;

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public abcdadapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> save,String[] images) {
    activity = a;

    dat=save;
    data=images;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return parent;
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    holder.text.setText(dat.get(position).get("NAME"));
 //   holder.image.setTag(data[position]);     // set your image from drawable
  //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.image);

    return vi;

}
```